# Exporting an unwieldy set of constants in a package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a package with a nontrivial list of constants I'd like to export to be available to users who load the package. What's the right way of doing so?

The only way I came up with that does what I want is to define the constants in the R code:

```
a = 1 # (no worries, I'm not using such silly names for the constants)
b = 2
...
z = 26
```

Then make sure to export them in the `NAMESPACE` file

```
export(a, b, c, ..., z)
```

The problems with this are:

1. It's quite tedious to type all of the constant names
2. The list of constants may change over time, and keeping track of exporting the constants in the namespace *as well as* separately managing their export in the `NAMESPACE` seems like a chore that's prone to mistakes (i.e., it's not very extensible)

The closest alternative I could come up with that *doesn't quite* work is to assign the constants to a list within the package, then `attach` the list:

```
consts = list(a = 1, b = 2, ..., z = 26)
```

Then define the `.onLoad` function appropriately:

```
.onLoad = function(libname, pkgname) {
  attach(consts)
}
```

The shortcoming of this is that `attach` creates a *new named environment* in the search list; this can add up to namespace cluttering, so I'd prefer the objects be attached *to the package environment* and then exported there. It seems the hitch with this comes from the `NAMESPACE` file. The closest thing I've seen to being helpful is the `exportPattern` function, but unfortunately there's no pattern that's not equivalent to just typing the names of the constants in the first place.

I played around a bit with `assign`, but the issue of the objects not being exported remains.

How can I overcome these issues so that the following code "just works"?

```
library(pkg_name)
a + b
# [1] 3 # <- expected output for this example
```

Comment: Can all the constants be saved as datasets? With lazyloading enabled, `a + b` should work - but I am not sure how much overhead this creates for you if you have many.

Comment: Would `list2env` help here?

Comment: @lmo cool function!! but I think it still runs into the `NAMESPACE` bottleneck -- I can `list2env` the objects into the package namespace, but not export them to show up on the regular search path :\

Comment: If it's helpful, `list2env` does have envir and parent arguments. You probably saw that already.

Comment: @lmo yes, but so does `assign`, which I had already tried (`assign` in a `for` loop is basically the same as `list2env`, i guess)

Comment: @lmo FWIW i just switched to using `list2env`, but it would be nice to be able to use `do.call` or `for` in the `NAMESPACE` file. Still have a problem of needing to copy paste some decoration into (1) `NAMESPACE` and to `\alias{}` calls in the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have yet to step into package construction (probably due to laziness) and haven't closely studied environment details for the past year, so am quite rusty. It seems strange to me that the NAMESPACE file won't execute standard R code like `do.call`. Perhaps such a comment / request might be worth posting on the R-dev list? Someone there might have some technique worked out or at least a stern response as to why such a technique is not recommended. I'm thinking of hadley's most recent request there, which resulted in some super cool code, as the best outcome.

Comment: @lmo yea I was a tad surprised myself. probably the recommendation is to use roxygen 